# Debugging: stepping through Python script using gdb?

Tags: python, debugging, gdb

Let's say we have the following mega-simple Python script:

```
print "Initializing"....
a=10
print "Variable value is %d" % (a)
print "All done!"
```

... and say, I'd like to debug this script by placing a breakpoint at line `a=10`, and then stepping through the script.

Now, I'd like to use `gdb` for this, because I'd like to debug Python bindings that may come as a part of a shared object (`.so`) library - hence, I'd ideally place a breakpoint on a Python code line, and then "step into" the C part of the shared object... (*Note that [DebuggingWithGdb - PythonInfo Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) doesn't really explicitly state that this is possible*)

The problem is: `gdb` on its own cannot really recognize breakpoints, placed on a Python script line:

```
$ gdb python
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.50.20110806-cvs 
...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b test.py:3
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y

Breakpoint 1 (test.py:3) pending.
(gdb) run test.py
Starting program: /usr/bin/python test.py
...
```

... and while the entire Python script does run within `gdb`, the breakpoint is simply never reached.

So - is what I want to do, at all possible with `gdb`; and if not, what other alternatives would I have for something similar?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Very interesting question. Here's my approach. Create `signal_test.py`:

```
import os
import signal

PID = os.getpid()

def do_nothing(*args):
    pass

def foo():
    print "Initializing..."
    a=10
    os.kill(PID, signal.SIGUSR1)
    print "Variable value is %d" % (a)
    print "All done!"

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, do_nothing)

foo()
```

Then you can run it under gdb:

```
$ gdb --args python signal_test.py
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-37.el5_7.1)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /net/gs/vol3/software/modules-sw/python/2.7/Linux/RHEL5/x86_64/bin/python...done.
```

And when you run it, it will go until you reach the call to `kill()`:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /net/gs/vol3/software/modules-sw/python/2.7/Linux/RHEL5/x86_64/bin/python signal_test.py
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Initializing...

Program received signal SIGUSR1, User defined signal 1.
0x0000003d340306f7 in kill () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

You can then look at a backtrace:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000003d340306f7 in kill () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004d82dd in posix_kill (self=<value optimized out>, args=<value optimized out>)
    at ./Modules/posixmodule.c:4047
#2  0x000000000049b574 in call_function (f=0x8aca30, throwflag=<value optimized out>)
    at Python/ceval.c:4012
#3  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=0x8aca30, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2665
#4  0x000000000049c5cd in call_function (f=0x8ac560, throwflag=<value optimized out>)
    at Python/ceval.c:4098
#5  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=0x8ac560, throwflag=<value optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:2665
#6  0x000000000049d3bb in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x2aaaae224f30, globals=<value optimized out>, 
    locals=<value optimized out>, args=0x0, argcount=0, kws=0x0, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, defcount=0, 
    closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3252
#7  0x000000000049d432 in PyEval_EvalCode (co=0x1a48, globals=0xa, locals=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:666
#8  0x00000000004bf321 in run_mod (fp=0x89ad60, filename=0x7fffffffb5b4 "signal_test.py", 
    start=<value optimized out>, globals=0x7e4680, locals=0x7e4680, closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffaee0)
    at Python/pythonrun.c:1346
#9  PyRun_FileExFlags (fp=0x89ad60, filename=0x7fffffffb5b4 "signal_test.py", 
    start=<value optimized out>, globals=0x7e4680, locals=0x7e4680, closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffaee0)
    at Python/pythonrun.c:1332
#10 0x00000000004bf5d8 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (fp=<value optimized out>, 
    filename=0x7fffffffb5b4 "signal_test.py", closeit=1, flags=0x7fffffffaee0)
    at Python/pythonrun.c:936
#11 0x00000000004148cc in Py_Main (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>)
    at Modules/main.c:599
#12 0x0000003d3401d994 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#13 0x0000000000413b19 in _start ()
```

If you continue on, the rest of the program will run normally.

```
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Variable value is 10
All done!

Program exited normally.
```

You can, instead, step through in the appropriate frame until you reach the statement you're interested in. You're probably going to want to run a debugging Python for this to make much sense.

Comment: Awesome @Michael Hoffman - many, many thanks for that answer! Accidentally, I also used used issuing a SIGTRAP from a C code in order to have `gdb` break where I wanted it to - but I never made a connection to Python (until now, that is :) ). Many thanks again - cheers!

Comment: I came up with a shorter version.
Just add this one-liner in your python script to set a breakpoint
```import os, signal; os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTRAP)```

Answer (score 26):

Apologies for the longish post; I came back again to a similar problem with debugging - a case where you take a long trip to the debugger, to finally reveal there is no actual bug - so I'd just like to post my notes and some code here (I'm still on Python 2.7, Ubuntu 11.04). In respect to the OP question - in newer `gdb`'s, its also possible to break by using the `id(...)` function in the Python script, and having `gdb` break on `builtin_id`; but here's more details:

Again, I had a problem with a C .so shared library module for Python; this time it was `svn.client`, which is a Swig module (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15856850/277826)); in Debian/Ubuntu available via `sudo apt-get install python-subversion` ([filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/python-subversion/filelist)). The problem occured while trying to run the [Example 8.3. A Python status crawler - Using the APIs (svnbook)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.developer.usingapi.html#svn.developer.usingapi.otherlangs.ex-2) This example should do the same that the terminal command `svn status` does; but when I tried it on one of my working copies, it crashed with "*Error (22): Error converting entry in directory 'path' to UTF-8*", even if `svn status` has been processing the same working copy (WC) directory (for years now) - so I wanted to see where that came from. My version of the test script is [python-subversion-test.py](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/svn-py2.7/python-subversion-test.py); and my full debug log is in [logsvnpy.gz](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/svn-py2.7/logsvnpy.gz) (gzipped text file, ~188K uncompressed, should anyone want to wade through endless stepping and backtraces) - this being the abridged version. I have both Python 2.7 and 3.2 installed, but the 2.7 are default on Ubuntu 11.04:

```
$ ls -la $(which python python-dbg)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 2012-02-29 07:31 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 2013-04-07 03:01 /usr/bin/python-dbg -> python2.7-dbg
$ apt-show-versions -r 'python[^-]+'
libpython2.7/natty uptodate 2.7.1-5ubuntu2.2
libpython3.2/natty uptodate 3.2-1ubuntu1.2
python2.7/natty uptodate 2.7.1-5ubuntu2.2
python2.7-dbg/natty uptodate 2.7.1-5ubuntu2.2
python2.7-dev/natty uptodate 2.7.1-5ubuntu2.2
python2.7-minimal/natty uptodate 2.7.1-5ubuntu2.2
python3/natty uptodate 3.2-1ubuntu1
python3-minimal/natty uptodate 3.2-1ubuntu1
python3.2/natty uptodate 3.2-1ubuntu1.2
python3.2-minimal/natty uptodate 3.2-1ubuntu1.2
```

The first thing to note is how the Python example functions: there, to obtain the status of all files within a directory, first `svn.client.svn_client_status2` is called - aside from the path, also with `_status_callback` in the arguments, as a callback function in Python to be registered - and then blocks. While `status2` is blocking, the underlying module iterates through all files in the WC directory path; and for each file entry, it calls the registered `_status_callback` which should print out information about the entry. Once this recursion is over, `status2` exits. Thus, the UTF-8 failure must come from the underlying module. Inspecting this module further:

```
$ python -c 'import inspect,pprint,svn.client; pprint.pprint(inspect.getmembers(svn.client))' | grep status
 ('status', <function svn_client_status at 0xb7351f44>),
 ('status2', <function svn_client_status2 at 0xb7351f0c>),
 ('status3', <function svn_client_status3 at 0xb7351ed4>),
 ('status4', <function svn_client_status4 at 0xb7351e9c>),
 ('svn_client_status', <function svn_client_status at 0xb7351f44>),
 # ...
```

... reveals that there are other `statusX` functions - however, `status3` failed with the same UTF-8 error; while `status4` caused a segmentation fault (which becomes yet another problem to debug).

And again, as in my comment to [@EliBendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7412994/277826)'s answer, I wanted to issue a breakpoint in Python, so as to obtain some sort of a call stack of C functions later on, which would reveal where the problem occurs - without me getting into rebuilding the C modules from source; but it didn't turn out to be that easy.

### Python and gdb

First of all, one thing that can be very confusing is the relationship between `gdb` and Python; the typical resources coming up here are:

- http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb - mentions a `gdbinit` in "GDB Macros",
- That  [release27-maint/Misc/gdbinit](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Misc/gdbinit?view=markup) is in the Python source tree; defines `gdb` commands like `pylocals` and `pyframe`, but also mentions:

  > # NOTE: If you have gdb 7 or later, it supports debugging of Python directly
  >   # with embedded macros that you may find superior to what is in here.
  >   # See Tools/gdb/libpython.py and http://bugs.python.org/issue8032.
- [Features/EasierPythonDebugging - FedoraProject](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/EasierPythonDebugging) - has an example, mentions a Fedora `python-debuginfo` package, and `libpython`
- [Tools/gdb/libpython.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/gdb/libpython.py) is also in Python source tree, and it mentions:

  > From gdb 7 onwards, gdb's build can be configured --with-python, allowing gdb
  >   to be extended with Python code e.g. for library-specific data visualizations,
  >   such as for the C++ STL types.   ....
  >   This module embeds knowledge about the implementation details of libpython so
  >   that we can emit useful visualizations e.g. a string, a list, a dict, a frame
  >   giving file/line information and the state of local variables
- [cpython/Lib/test/test_gdb.py](https://github.com/akheron/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_gdb.py) - apparently from cpython, seems to test `gdb` functionality from Python

This gets a bit confusing - apart from the pointer, that one better get themselves `gdb` v.7; I managed to get for my OS:

```
$ apt-show-versions gdb
gdb 7.3-50.20110806-cvs newer than version in archive
```

A quick way to test if `gdb` supports Python is this:

```
$ gdb --batch --eval-command="python print gdb"
<module 'gdb' (built-in)>
$ python -c 'import gdb; print gdb'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gdb
```

... but `gdb` supporting Python, doesn't mean Python on its own can access `gdb` functionality (apparently, the `gdb` has its own built-in separate Python interpreter).

It turns out, in Ubuntu 11.04, the `python2.7-dbg` package installs a file `libpython2.7.so.1.0-gdb.py`:

```
$ find / -xdev -name '*libpython*' 2>/dev/null | grep '\.py'
/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0-gdb.py
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0-gdb.py /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libpython.py
```

... and this is the one corresponding to the mentioned `Tools/gdb/libpython.py`; the symlinking will allow us to refer to it as `libpython`, and use import script mentioned in  [Features/EasierPythonDebugging](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/EasierPythonDebugging) .

The `test_gdb.py` script is actually for Python 3 - I have modified it for 2.7, and posted in [test_gdb2.7.py](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/gdb-py2.7/test_gdb2.7.py). This script calls `gdb` through an OS system call, and tests its Python functionality, with printouts to stdout; it also accepts a command line option, `-imp-lp`, which will `import libpython` in `gdb` before other commands are executed. So, for instance:

```
$ python-dbg test_gdb2.7.py
...
*** test_prettyprint ***

42 (self=0x0, v=0x8333fc8)
[] (self=0x0, v=0xb7f7506c)
('foo', 'bar', 'baz') (self=0x0, v=0xb7f7d234)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] (self=0x0, v=0xb7f7506c)
...

$ python-dbg test_gdb2.7.py -imp-lp
...
*** test_prettyprint ***

42 (self=0x0, v=42)
[] (self=0x0, v=[])
('foo', 'bar', 'baz') (self=0x0, v=('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] (self=0x0, v=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
...
```

Thus, `libpython.py` is intended specifically for the Python interpreter inside `gdb`, and it helps `gdb` print Python representations (`v=[]`) instead of just memory addresses (`v=0xb7f7506c`) - which is only helpful, *if* `gdb` happens to debug a Python script (or rather, it will debug the Python executable, that interprets the script).

The `test_gdb.py` script also gives the pointer that you can "*... run "python -c'id(DATA)'" under gdb with a breakpoint on `builtin_id`*"; for testing this, I have posted a bash script, [gdb_py_so_test.sh](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/gdb-py2.7/gdb_py_so_test.sh), which creates an executable with a counting thread function, and both plain distutils and swig modules (in both debug and release versions) that interface to the same function. It also creates a `.gdbinit` with both `gdb` and `gdb`'s Python class breakpoints - and finally it runs `gdb` on Python (loading one of the shared modules), where the user can hopefully see if the breakpoints are really triggering.

### segfault in gdb without source rebuild

First I focused on the `status4` segfault, and I wanted to know exactly which module does the function come from. I used a function, that can be found in [debug_funcs.py](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/gdb-py2.7/debug_funcs.py); which can be called with separate regex for functions and modules, and may generate something like:

```
$ python python-subversion-test.py ./MyRepoWCDir
# ...
# example for debug_funcs.showLoadedModules(r'(?=.*\.(so|pyc))(?=.*svn)(?=.*client)')
#
svn.client 0xb74b83d4L <module 'svn.client' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/svn/client.pyc'>
_client 0xb7415614L <module '_client' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/libsvn/_client.so'>
libsvn.client 0xb74155b4L <module 'libsvn.client' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/libsvn/client.pyc'>
#
# example for debug_funcs.showFunctionsInLoadedModules(r'status4', r'(?=.*\.(so|pyc))(?=.*svn)')
#
0xb738c4fcL libsvn.client   svn_client_status4                       libsvn/client.pyc
0xb74e9eecL _client         svn_client_status4                       libsvn/_client.so
0xb738c4fcL svn.client      status4                                  svn/client.pyc
0xb738c4fcL svn.client      svn_client_status4                       svn/client.pyc
```

However, note that:

```
$ python-dbg python-subversion-test.py ./MyRepoWCDir
# ...
0x90fc574 - _client         /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/libsvn/_client_d.so
# ...
0x912b30c _client         svn_client_status4                       libsvn/_client_d.so
# ...
$ apt-show-versions -r python-subversion
python-subversion/natty uptodate 1.6.12dfsg-4ubuntu2.1
python-subversion-dbg/natty uptodate 1.6.12dfsg-4ubuntu2.1
```

... `python-dbg` will load different (debug, `_d`) versions of the `.so` modules of `libsvn` (or `python-subversion`); and that is because I have the `python-subversion-dbg` package installed.

In any case, we may think we know the adresses where modules and respective functions are loaded upon each Python script call - which would allow us to place a `gdb` breakpoint on a [program address](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html#Specify-Location); given that here we work with "vanilla" .so's (that haven't been rebuilt from source). However, Python on its own cannot see that `_client.so` in fact utilizes `libsvn_client-1.so`:

```
$ ls -la $(locate '*2.7*/_client*.so')  #check locations
$ ls -la $(locate 'libsvn_client')      #check locations
$ ldd /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libsvn/_client.so | grep client
  libsvn_client-1.so.1 => /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1 (0x0037f000)
#
# instead of nm, also can use:
# objdump -dSlr file | grep '^[[:digit:]].*status4' | grep -v '^$\|^[[:space:]]'
#
$ nm -D /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libsvn/_client.so | grep status4
         U svn_client_status4
$ nm -a /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/libsvn/_client_d.so | grep status4
00029a50 t _wrap_svn_client_status4
         U svn_client_status4
$ nm -D /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1 | grep status4                    # -a: no symbols
00038c10 T svn_client_status4
```

From within Python, we could make a system call, to query `/proc/pid/maps` for the address where `libsvn_client-1.so` is loaded, and add to it the address reported by the last `nm -D` command for the offset of `svn_client_status4`; and obtain the address where we could break in `gdb` (with the `b *0xAddress` syntax) - but that is not necessarry, because if `nm` can see the symbol, so can `gdb` - so we can break directly on the function name. Another thing is that in case of a segfault, `gdb` stops on its own, and we can issue a backtrace (note: use Ctrl-X A to exit the gdb TUI mode after `layout asm`):

```
$ gdb --args python python-subversion-test.py ./AudioFPGA/
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/python python-subversion-test.py ./MyRepoWCDir
...
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x005a5bf3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1
#2  0x005dbf4a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so.1
#3  0x005dcea3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so.1
#4  0x005dd240 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so.1
#5  0x005a5fe5 in svn_client_status4 () from /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1
#6  0x00d54dae in ?? () from /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/libsvn/_client.so
#7  0x080e0155 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
...
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x005a5bf3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1
(gdb) list
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) disas
No function contains program counter for selected frame.
(gdb) x/10i 0x005a5bf3
=> 0x5a5bf3:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%ebx
   0x5a5bf6:    mov    -0x8(%ebp),%esi
   0x5a5bf9:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edi
   0x5a5bfc:    mov    %ebp,%esp
(gdb) layout asm  # No function contains program counter for selected frame (cannot show 0x5a5bf3)
(gdb) p svn_client_status4
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x5a5c10 <svn_client_status4>
(gdb) frame 5
#5  0x005a5fe5 in svn_client_status4 () from /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1
(gdb) list
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) layout asm
 │0x5a5fd8 <svn_client_status4+968>       mov    %esi,0x4(%esp)                                |
 │0x5a5fdc <svn_client_status4+972>       mov    %eax,(%esp)                                   |
 │0x5a5fdf <svn_client_status4+975>       mov    -0x28(%ebp),%eax                              |
 │0x5a5fe2 <svn_client_status4+978>       call   *0x38(%eax)                                   |
>│0x5a5fe5 <svn_client_status4+981>       test   %eax,%eax                                     |
 │0x5a5fe7 <svn_client_status4+983>       jne    0x5a5ce3 <svn_client_status4+211>             |
 │0x5a5fed <svn_client_status4+989>       jmp    0x5a5ee3 <svn_client_status4+723>             |
 │0x5a5ff2 <svn_client_status4+994>       lea    -0x1fac(%ebx),%eax                            |
 │0x5a5ff8 <svn_client_status4+1000>      mov    %eax,(%esp)                                   |
```

So, our error happens somewhere in `libsvn_client-1.so`, but in memory area before `svn_client_status4` function start; and since we don't have debugging symbols - we cannot say much else than that. Using `python-dbg` may give bit different results:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x005aebf0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x005aebf0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1
#1  0x005e4f4a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so.1
#2  0x005e5ea3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so.1
#3  0x005e6240 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libsvn_wc-1.so.1
#4  0x005aefe5 in svn_client_status4 () from /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1
#5  0x00d61e9e in _wrap_svn_client_status4 (self=0x0, args=0x8471214)
    at /build/buildd/subversion-1.6.12dfsg/subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.c:10001
...
(gdb) frame 4
#4  0x005aefe5 in svn_client_status4 () from /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1
(gdb) list
9876    in /build/buildd/subversion-1.6.12dfsg/subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.c
(gdb) p svn_client_status4
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x5aec10 <svn_client_status4>
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
...
0x00497a20  0x004c8be8  Yes         /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/libsvn/_core_d.so
0x004e9fe0  0x004f52c8  Yes         /usr/lib/libsvn_swig_py2.7_d-1.so.1
0x004f9750  0x00501678  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libsvn_diff-1.so.1
0x0050f3e0  0x00539d08  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libsvn_subr-1.so.1
0x00552200  0x00572658  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0
0x0057ddb0  0x005b14b8  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1
...
0x00c2a8f0  0x00d11cc8  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
0x00d3f860  0x00d6dc08  Yes         /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/libsvn/_client_d.so
...
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

... but the `list` command still gives us a source line belonging to frame 5 (not frame 4), and we still don't know more about `svn_client_status4`: while the `python-subversion` modules are loaded in their debug versions, debugging information is missing for `libsvn_client-1.so`. So, time to rebuild from source.

### segfault in gdb with source rebuild

It is the actual `subversion` that we need to rebuild, or rather it's library part - since we already have debug modules from `python-subversion`; the package on my system is called `libsvn1`:

```
$ apt-show-versions -r 'libsvn'
libsvn1/natty uptodate 1.6.12dfsg-4ubuntu2.1
$ apt-cache search 'libsvn' | grep 'dbg'
python-subversion-dbg - Python bindings for Subversion (debug extension)
```

... and there is no debug package for it. To rebuild from source, I went through `apt-get source libsvn1`, with dependencies manually found via `apt-rdepends --build-depends --follow=DEPENDS subversion`. There are more details in the full log - but here we can note that the source package can built both the SWIG Python bindings (that is, `python-subversion`) and the Subversion library (`libsvn1`). Also, I ran `make install` with a location out of the main kernel tree; that means, that one had to explicitly specify the source-built modules via LD environment variables:

```
$ ELD=/path/to/src/subversion-1.6.12dfsg/tmpinst/usr/local/lib
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ELD:$ELD/svn-python/libsvn LD_PRELOAD="$ELD/libsvn_client-1.so $ELD/svn-python/libsvn/_core.so" gdb --args python python-subversion-test.py ./MyRepoWCDir
```

One tricky thing here is that building SWIG debug modules requires a call with `python-dbg`; apparently just doing `./configure --enable-debug` doesn't do that; and so, just `_core.so`, etc are produced, albeit with debugging information. If we then try to enforce its loading as with the above command, but with `python-dbg`, we will get `undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4`, because:

```
$ objdump -d $(which python) | grep '^\w.*InitMod'
0813b770 <Py_InitModule4>:
$ objdump -d $(which python-dbg) | grep '^\w.*InitMod'
08124740 <Py_InitModule4TraceRefs>:
```

... `python-dbg` has a different `Py_InitModule4` function. That, however, wasn't a problem, because simply `python` was used (as in the above invocation), and `gdb` still allowed stepping through the relevant functions in the newly built `libsvn` (the mentioned Bash script  [gdb_py_so_test.sh](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/gdb-py2.7/gdb_py_so_test.sh), as an example builds a basic Swig module in both debug and release versions to confirm the right procedure).

With debugging symbols for `libsvn`, the function call stack looks like this (pasted a bit differently):

```
#5  0x0016e654 in svn_client_status4 (...,    libsvn_client/status.c:369
  #4  0x007fd209 in close_edit (...,            libsvn_wc/status.c:2144
    #3  0x007fafaa in get_dir_status (...,        libsvn_wc/status.c:1033
      #2  0x007fa4e7 in send_unversioned_item (..., libsvn_wc/status.c:722
        #1  0x0016dd17 in tweak_status (...,          libsvn_client/status.c:81
          #0 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

... and since the same library functions are also used by command line `svn client`, we can compare, in say, frame 5:

```
# `svn status`:
(gdb) p *(sb->real_status_func)
$3 = {svn_error_t *(void *, const char *, svn_wc_status2_t *, apr_pool_t *)} 0x805e199 <print_status>
...
# `python python-subversion-test.py`
(gdb) p *(svn_wc_status_func3_t*)sb->real_status_func
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

So, in case of a Python call to `status4`, `sb->real_status_func` is NULL, causing a segfault. The reason for this can be revealed once we start reading the source: in `./subversion/libsvn_client/deprecated.c`, the definition for `status3` has:

```
svn_client_status3(svn_revnum_t *result_rev,
                   const char *path,
                   const svn_opt_revision_t *revision,
                   svn_wc_status_func2_t status_func,
                   void *status_baton,
....
  struct status3_wrapper_baton swb = { 0 };
  swb.old_func = status_func;
  swb.old_baton = status_baton;
  return svn_client_status4(result_rev, path, revision, status3_wrapper_func,
                            &swb, depth, get_all, update, no_ignore,
                            ignore_externals, changelists, ctx, pool);
```

... that is, when `status3` is called with a callback function, it creates a struct, and assigns the function to one of the struct properties - and then uses the struct in the further call to `status4`! Since `status3` actually works from Python - the conclusion is that we cannot correctly call `status4` from Python (since that would involve creating a C struct in Python); and that doesn't matter anyways, because we can call `status3` from Python - which then itself calls `status4`!

Then why is `status4` addressible from Python? Probably because `swig` simply autogenerated an interface for it... In any case, here is an example, where a trip to the debugger reveals the source of the problem - but not really a bug `:)` Solution? Don't use `status4`.

### C failure in Python module, in gdb with source rebuild

Going back to the UTF-8 failure, which occured with `status2` and `status3` - it was easier, given that now source built versions of the modules were available. The problem was obvious in the function `entry_name_to_utf8`, and by exploring it's argument `name`, one could first realize that the file name causing the problem, did indeed contain non-ascii - but still legal UTF-8 characters (see [Program to check/look up UTF-8/Unicode characters in string on command line? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/581523/program-to-check-look-up-utf-8-unicode-characters-in-string-on-command-line/581529#581529)). I have then used this [.gdbinit](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/svn-py2.7/gdbinit), to make a Python class breakpoint for gdb, that would print out the filenames, and break only on match with the problematic one.

Then the question is - how come, the command line client `svn status` does not crash on the same filename? By stepping through both `svn status` and `python python-subversion-test.py`, one can compare the respective function call stacks:

```
# call stack Python module:
#
_wrap_svn_client_status3    subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.c * allocs:
(svn_swig_py_get_pool_arg(args, SWIGTYPE_p_apr_pool_t, &_global_py_pool, &_global_pool))
  svn_client_status3    subversion/libsvn_client/deprecated.c
    svn_client_status4    subversion/libsvn_client/status.c
      close_edit    subversion/libsvn_wc/status.c
        get_dir_status    subversion/libsvn_wc/status.c

# call stack svn client:
#
main    subversion/svn/main.c
  svn_cl__status    subversion/svn/status-cmd.c * allocs
  (subpool = svn_pool_create(pool))
    svn_client_status4    subversion/libsvn_client/status.c
      close_edit    subversion/libsvn_delta/cancel.c
        close_edit    subversion/libsvn_wc/status.c
          get_dir_status    subversion/libsvn_wc/status.c


# svn call stack:
# ... svn_client_status4 - starts pool
#
get_dir_status    subversion/libsvn_wc/status.c
  handle_dir_entry    subversion/libsvn_wc/status.c
    get_dir_status    subversion/libsvn_wc/status.c
      svn_io_get_dirents2    subversion/libsvn_subr/io.c
        entry_name_to_utf8    subversion/libsvn_subr/io.c
          svn_path_cstring_to_utf8    subversion/libsvn_subr/path.c
            svn_utf_cstring_to_utf8    subversion/libsvn_subr/utf.c   * from here, bad node->handle
              convert_cstring    subversion/libsvn_subr/utf.c
                convert_to_stringbuf    subversion/libsvn_subr/utf.c  * here, bad node => fail
```

At this point, one encounters the fact that Subversion uses `libapr` (Apache Portable Runtime) for memory allocation; and it is in fact this part causing the failure - principally, the function `apr_xlate_conv_buffer` behaves differently in the two cases.

But, it can be rather difficult to see what the actual problem is here, because `apr_xlate_conv_buffer` uses an encoding in `node->frompage`, which is set to the define `APR_LOCALE_CHARSET 1` - and that doesn't change between `svn status` and Python cases. To come down to this, I've copy-pasted everything related to APR string copying and allocation down the call stack, and reconstructed a simple example that builds a Swig  module, that should just copy a string using APR runtime; that example is in the directory [aprtest](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/aprtest/), built with the bash script [build-aprtest.sh](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/aprtest/build-aprtest.sh).

Thanks to that example, it was revealed that the UTF failure problem can be fixed by calling `setlocale` in C before any APR string memory allocation - for more about that test, see [#15977257 - Using utf-8 input for cmd Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334664/using-utf-8-input-for-cmd-python-module/15977257#15977257). Correspondingly, all we need to do from Python is execute:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

... before any calls to `svn.client` (and thus to `libsvn`, and thus to `libapr`). And here we have yet another example, for a trip to the debugger, without really having a bug `:)`

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question, and I'm eagerly waiting for other answers, but for now:

The document http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb is mainly for debugging segfaults and hung Python processes, not for normal stepping through Python code.

I'm not sure I understand your intention 100%. Do you want to break in your C (Python C API) code once a certain Python line is reached? Then wouldn't it be just a matter of doing:

```
# some Python code
# some other Python code
myobj.foo()
# some other Python code
```

Where `myobj.foo()` calls into the C API. Then, just place a breakpoint on the function attached to `myobj.foo` and you have your breakpoint at the right location. Do you need more functionality, or are you simply looking for a more natural way to achieve the same?

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @Eli Bendersky! Point is, I'd like to debug [pysmbc](http://cyberelk.net/tim/); that is a Python lib, that comes in a form of an .so file (compiled from C sources) ... The thing is, I could probably get the source, and add the breakpoint directly in the C file; however, that means I'd have to read all sources, and find the exact entry point of the Python function; however that asks for detailed reading == time. I thought, if I could 'break' at Python, then "step into", and issue a backtrace, I'd have easier time to find what actual C code has been called.. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem of debugging an already running python script. I used PyCharm's "Attach to process" ([Attach a process](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attaching-to-local-process.html)) utility to set breakpoints and was actually able to set breakpoints and dump the variables I was interested in.
The main challenge was the script was already running for last 20hrs and I didn't want to modify that script and start again. Hence, I attached an already running process.

For production cases where using an IDE is not possible, one may try to remotely debug the scripts [Remote Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html)