# Using utf-8 input for cmd Python module

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, command-line-interface

In the process of creating a small CLI notebook application, I decided to go with the [`cmd`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) Python library (see also [`cmd`](http://pymotw.com/2/cmd/index.html#module-cmd) on PyMOTW).

My shell is UTF-8.

```
→ echo $LANG
fr_FR.utf-8
→ echo $LC_ALL
fr_FR.utf-8
```

And it is working quite well.

```
→ echo "東京"
東京
```

Starting the code of my little app and trying to use utf-8:

```
→ python nb.py 
log> foobar
2013-01-15 foobar
log> æ±äº¬
2013-01-15 æ±äº¬
```

**Edited** The expected input/output is. When I type utf-8 characters, be accent or Japanese characters in that case, I get garbage.

```
log> 東京
2013-01-15 東京
```

So when starting the program the command line changes the type of the input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# encoding: utf-8
import datetime
import os.path
import logging
import cmd

ROOT = "~/test/"
NOTENAME = "notes.md"

def todaynotepath(rootpath, notename):
    isodate = datetime.date.today().isoformat()
    isodate.replace("-", "/")
    return rootpath + isodate.replace("-", "/") + "/%s" % (notename)

def addcontent(content):
    logging.info(content)

class NoteBook(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple cli notebook."""
    prompt = "log> "

    def precmd(self, line):
        # What is the date path NOW
        notepath = todaynotepath(ROOT, NOTENAME)
        # if the directory of the note doesn't exist, create it.
        notedir = os.path.dirname(notepath)
        if not os.path.exists(notedir):
            os.makedirs(notedir)
        # if the file for notes today doesn't exist, create it.
        logging.basicConfig(filename=notepath, level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        return cmd.Cmd.precmd(self, line)

    def default(self, line):
        if line:
            print datetime.date.today().isoformat(), line
            addcontent(line)

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True

    def postloop(self):
        print

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NoteBook().cmdloop()
```

So I guess there might be things to override in the original Class of cmd. I checked the module but without luck yet.

Edit 2: Added `LESSCHARSET` as recommended by @dda

```
LANG=fr_FR.utf-8
LANGUAGE=fr_FR.utf-8
LC_ALL=fr_FR.utf-8
LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LESSCHARSET=utf-8
```

Comment: From your example output of your app it's not clear to me what is going wrong. Can show what you'd like to see.

Comment: Unrelated note: this program creates a directory named `~` instead of creating a dir inside the user's home (which I expect is the intended behaviour). You can use `os.path.expanduser` to get the correct path from home.

Comment: @lbonn because I changed the real path to `~` for stackoverflow only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me, Karl. See this:

```
dda$ ./nb.py 
log> tagada
2013-01-15 tagada
log> 香港
2013-01-15 香港
log>
```

And the `notes.md` file contains the proper entries. So I don't think it's `cmd` that's at fault here, but probably something in your terminal settings. Try adding

```
export LESSCHARSET=utf-8
```

in your `.profile`.

Comment: ah interesting. I still have the issue even with `LESSCHARSET` set to the right value. But it means there is a difference in our config.

Comment: what is the version of Python, you are using? And do you have any specific configuration for it?

Comment: In that case I used the same Python 2.7 as you did. Specifically I have Python 2.7.2. Versions 2.5.4 and 2.6.1 didn't work.

Comment: I guess I will accept this answer. Because it is working for you. I have to figure out what is not working for me :)

Comment: I'm still on 10.6.8, but I don't think that's much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I thought there was another question like this on SO, but specifically for a C shared library module; this answer may have been more appropriate there, but I cannot find the link now `:)`

In brief, my answer would be - try `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` before you load the module (I haven't used `cmd` myself yet). In more detail:

I was trying to use the SWIG Python bindings for Subversion (SVN). These are basically an automatic interface for Python produced by SWIG, directly from SVN C library code (`libsvn1`). When I run `svn status MyWorkingCopy` from the terminal, it hooks into `libsvn` code - and it hasn't failed for years now (for that repository). But, when I ran the Python example (doing the same thing as `svn status`) - which hooks into the same `libsvn` code - from the same terminal, then I'd get a UTF-8 related error from libsvn/SWIG, which would crash my Python script.

This means that Python somehow "influenced" the library to behave otherwise in respect to character sets. But my terminal persistently reports:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
...
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

So, it's not about what the terminal/shell (`bash` in this case) think - it's about what the underlying C code (of `libsvn` in this case) thinks about current settings. And the same, I thought, applies to python:

```
$ python -c 'import locale; print locale.getdefaultlocale()'
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

So, now it's about seeing what C code sees, when ran from terminal vs. when ran from Python (in the same terminal). Debugging `libsvn` further, it turned out it actually comes from another library, `libapr` (Apache Portable Runtime), which SVN uses for memory allocation. What I ended up doing, is writing a repeat of the string copying done by `libsvn` which uses `libapr` in a standalone C program; and then built it via SWIG as a Python module. This program, `aprtest`, accepts a string as argument, invokes the `libapr` engine to copy it, and displays the result; the source for it is posted here:

- http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/aprtest/

See the script [build-aprtest.sh](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/aprtest/build-aprtest.sh) for library versions I worked with (Ubuntu 11.04); to build, run `bash build-aprtest.sh`.

Now, if you run the executable thus built in terminal, you get:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
...
$ ./aprtest "test"
LC_CTYPE 0 CODESET 14
ANSI_X3.4-1968
apr_xlate_open: apr_err=0
apr_xlate_conv_buffer apr_err == 0 
(*dest)->data: test
$ ./aprtest "test東京"
LC_CTYPE 0 CODESET 14
ANSI_X3.4-1968
apr_xlate_open: apr_err=0
apr_xlate_conv_buffer apr_err == 22
```

The `libapr` engine clearly failed on UTF-8 input from command line, in spite of the terminal reporting `UTF-8`. And when we run as a shared module (called `aprtest_s`) through Python:

```
$ python -c 'import aprtest_s; aprtest_s.pysmain("test")'
LC_CTYPE 0 CODESET 14
ANSI_X3.4-1968
apr_xlate_open: apr_err=0
apr_xlate_conv_buffer apr_err == 0 
(*dest)->data: test
$ python -c 'import aprtest_s; aprtest_s.pysmain("test東京")'
LC_CTYPE 0 CODESET 14
ANSI_X3.4-1968
apr_xlate_open: apr_err=0
apr_xlate_conv_buffer apr_err == 22
```

... the same happens (*btw, for the same issue with SVN and APR, but for Perl, see [Is there a variable or function that returns the native platform encoding (APR_LOCALE_CHARSET)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=740533)*). So we can conclude:

- It doesn't matter if the C program is ran directly from terminal, or through Python - the C program simply sees a different locale/encoding settings, from what the calling program may see
- There is no problem with ASCII strings, only the UTF-8 ones

So, how then does the svn client work properly from terminal, while ultimately using `libapr` without crashing? Well, as it can be seen it the comments of source for [aprtest_s.c](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/dbg/swig-py/aprtest/aprtest_s.c); it is by setting the program's own locale, by using the C function `setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"")`, which, it turns out, sets [all the categories of the locale of the process](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setlocale.html). This issue is actually mentioned in [apr-dev mailing list: Re: Misbehaviour of apr_os_locale_encoding on Windows](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/apr-dev/201004.mbox/%3c4BC4B92D.2000500@xbc.nu%3e):

> ... this picking of one
>   of the 55 different current locales can probably only be properly done
>   by the application, not by APR.

So, by coding `setlocale()` in the C application, we apparently pick the default locale explicitly, so `libapr` knows about it. In the test case, this call to `setlocale` must happen before a call to `apr_xlate_open`.

Now, the posted version of `aprtest` doesn't do `setlocale`, so we can see what is happening from Python (note also [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t730678-how-does-python-get-the-value-for-sys-stdin-encoding.html)), when we use the Python version, `locale.setlocale()`:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8' echo 'import sys;print sys.stdin.encoding' | python
None
$ echo 'import sys;print sys.stdin.encoding' | PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8' python
utf-8
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
...
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Sep 27 2012, 21:16:52) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import aprtest_s
>>> aprtest_s.print_locale()
LC_CTYPE 0 CODESET 14
ANSI_X3.4-1968
>>> aprtest_s.pysmain("test")
LC_CTYPE 0 CODESET 14
ANSI_X3.4-1968
apr_xlate_open: apr_err=0
apr_xlate_conv_buffer apr_err == 0 
(*dest)->data: test
>>> aprtest_s.pysmain("test東京")
LC_CTYPE 0 CODESET 14
ANSI_X3.4-1968
apr_xlate_open: apr_err=0
apr_xlate_conv_buffer apr_err == 22 
>>> import locale
>>> print locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
>>> print locale.getlocale()
(None, None)
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.stdin.encoding
UTF-8
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> print sys.stdin.encoding
UTF-8
>>> print locale.getlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
>>> aprtest_s.pysmain("test")
LC_CTYPE 0 CODESET 14
UTF-8
apr_xlate_open: apr_err=0
apr_xlate_conv_buffer apr_err == 0 
(*dest)->data: test
>>> aprtest_s.pysmain("test東京")
LC_CTYPE 0 CODESET 14
UTF-8
apr_xlate_open: apr_err=0
apr_xlate_conv_buffer apr_err == 0 
(*dest)->data: test東京
>>>
```

Thus, to make sure what is it, that a C application sees in Python - use `locale.getlocale()` (<s>NOT `locale.getdefaultlocale()`</s>). The way I understand it now, `getdefaultlocale` returns some OS/user settings saved somewhere which are *considered* to be default, but necessarily *applied* as default when an application starts; and `getlocale` gets the actual, currently applied locale settings. And I guess, when we call `setlocale` with empty string, that causes the rest of the code to: read the default settings (those given by `getdefaultlocale`), and *then* apply the default settings as current.

And a s final note - even though it looks related, the encoding settings of `stdin`/`stdout` (apparently) have nothing to do with the encoding of the current locale (at least as seen by a C program running in that environment).

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!